# BASH - Replace substring "$$" with substring "$$$"

Tags: bash

Essentially what I am trying to do is take a string with a bunch of text and if it has a substring of "$$" to replace it with a substring of "$$$"

ex:

```
string="abcde\$\$fghi"
# Modify string
echo $string 
# ^ should give "abcde$$$fghi"
```

I have been at this for like 2 hours now and it seems like a very simple thing, so if anyone could provide some help then I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT: Changed original string in the question from `"abcde$$fghi"` to `"abcde\$\$fghi"`

Comment: Where do you get the string from? Because `string="abcde$$fghi"` won't come out as is, you'd have to do `string="abcde\$\$fghi"`

Comment: `$$` is a special variable in the shell, it contains the ID of the current process. The variables are expanded in double quotes, therefore `string` does not contain `$$` but a number (the PID of shell) instead. Enclose the string in apostrophes (single quotes) to get `$$` inside it.

Comment: `echo $string` can be very misleading in some situations (see ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)). `echo "$string"` is better, and `printf '%s\n' "$string"` is better still. `declare -p string` (note the lack of `$`) can also help clarify what's actually stored in the variable (or array).

Answer (score 3):

`$$` is a special variable in the shell, it contains the ID of the current process. The variables are expanded in double quotes, therefore `string` does not contain `$$` but a number (the PID of shell) instead.
Enclose the string in apostrophes (single quotes) to get `$$` inside it.

The replacement you need can be done in multiple ways. The simplest way (probably) and also the fastest way (for sure) is to use `/` in the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of `$string`:

```sh
echo "${string/'$$'/'$$$'}"
```

To make it work you have to use the same trick as before: wrap `$$` and `$$$` in single quotes to prevent the shell replace them with something else. The quotes around the entire expression are needed to preserve the space characters contained by `$string`, otherwise the line is split to words by whitspaces and and `echo` outputs these words separated by one space character.

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v7ikKDMv3VY9MSk5JVVFJS09I1OdKzU5I19BpRoip6@uoqIOIlTUa///BwA).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put in the backslashes in my original question. Could you modify your answer to use double quotes instead of single? I edited it just now.

Comment: The answer does not depend on the way you initialize `$string`. You can use the [heredoc syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) as well, or read it from a file. The way to print a string that replaces `$$` with `$$$` in `$string` is the same and it is described in this answer. You need to wrap `${...}` in double quotes to preserve the spaces inside `$string` but that's the only reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you quote the string with single quote marks (i.e. `string='abcde$$fghi'`) you can do the replacement with `echo "${string/'$$'/'$$$'}"`

Edit: this is basically what @axiac said in their comment

Comment: Well, I only said about wrapping `$$` in apostrophes in my comment and it is a remark about a flaw in the code posted in the question but it does not answer the question. The rest of the answer is yours and it deserves an upvote.